# Can I import an existing table automatically changing primary keys?

Tags: mysql, sql, import, overwrite

I have a table about permissions in my server coming from an previous version of my website, and I need to keep them, but newest web app version has it's own and probably needed basic configurations in this table.

So, I need to import the vanilla data into my table (or viceversa, same result) without overwritting or skipping existing primary keys, this means, automatically updating primary keys to others unused. Is this possible? How?

Comment: Can you store the old permissions data in a different table from the new permissions data or will you need to store them in the same table?  Are you aiming to continue using the same Primary Key system as before or does this newest web app mean you will need to start a new Primary Key system for the new Web App?

Comment: I need to insert all permissions together. The PK system should be the same.

Comment: Is the primary an autoincrement field?

Comment: No, it's default to NULL with no Extra config.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. Use a `INSERT INTO .. SELECT FROM` construct like

```
insert into new_table(col1, col2, ...,coln)
select col1, col2, ...,coln from old_table;
```

None, just don't include your PK column in the insert statement and thus if in your imported table PK is an synthetic or auto incremented column then it will generated automatically.

Comment: How will this change conflicting PKs? Does it change existing PKs or the imported ones?

Comment: It's not autoincremented, but don't know if it's synthetic, how can I check it?

Comment: @Phazoner, check your table schema (create table script)

Comment: `show create table t` shows it's not synthetic. So... Will PK generation a problem?

Comment: How did you determine the primary key in the old system?

Comment: @Phazoner, it depends? how you are generating the PK in new table currently, you can follow the same else consider importing the existing PK value from old table. BTW, this information's should be cleared beforehand

Comment: I don't know is it being generated, it's managed by Liferay 7... The need of trying this is because I'm getting permissions errors and this type of errors can be produced by lack of this permissions in the database (they're not all autogenerated when I remove them). So upgrading my db from L6 to L7 may have left some permissions unconfigured.

Answer (score 0):

The following is an example of my suggested statement structure -

```
INSERT INTO tblNewPermissions ( permissionsID,
                                oldPermission1,
                                oldPermission2,
                                newPermission1,
                                newPermission2 )
SELECT permissionsID,
       permission1,
       permission2,
       "newPermission1DefaultValue",
       "newPermission2DefaultValue"
FROM tblOldPermissions;
```

Note : You will need to ensure that the fields in the new table that are used to store the old data have matching data types.

Note : This approach assumes that the primary key is not an autoincrement field.

If there are any questions or comments on this answer, then please feel free to post a comment accordingly.

Comment: are you not essentially giving the same answer I have already posted?

Comment: Your answer makes no explicit reference to the primary key in the fields list and whilst it does show how the old permisiions can be imported it does not show how they can be integrated with the new data.

Comment: Also, we have can not safely assume that the Primary key is being automatically generated.  Judging by the original question and the answers to my follow up questions it is likely that the primary key from the old records (which will constitute the primary key for the new records) will need to be imported and thus explicitly referenced in the SQL statement.

Comment: It's pretty similar, in this case I assume he proposes to manually choose the info written in some fields of the imported resources from the other table. Now I ask, this insert will come from other database in the same server, so I think it'll go on OK with "from othertable.tableoldpermissions", right?

Comment: Yes, use oldDB.tblOldPermissions.